# How to change or configure LDAP/AD URL in asp.net core 2 mvc

Tags: c#, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

I gone through few links for configuring AD authentication with asp.net core 2. As given in documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?tabs=aspnetcore2x) there is simplest way to configure windows authentication by just selecting at the beginning of the application creation. but as given on above link, it is only for only IISExpress. Just couldn't understand what if I have remote Active directory on server machine and having multiple developer machines, which are in domain then how can we set up each developer machine with AD authentication. I mean where need to set up all these LDAP Url and Directory service in asp.net core 2. As per my understanding asp.net core 2 does not support Directory services libraries? always need to use third party. But how

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. ASP.NET Core works perfectly with AD-based Windows authentication and whether it's IIS or IIS Express is irrelevant

Comment: Oh! but when I will deploy application on remote server say on Azure or client's production server, then where i need to configure LDAP for my application ?

Comment: It will use the AD connected to that server by default

Comment: Absolutely correct. But then I do need to install VS on server machine to create application.No. Where I can set up all these AD configuration in application? in startup?

Comment: What? Since when do you install VS to install an application on a server? That's new to me. You cannot configure it as ASP.NET Core just handles the job over to IIS where you configure that. If you want to use custom servers (NOT the one you are connected to), you'll need to disable Windows Authentication and do it all manually with the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement libary

Comment: No no. not for install application. I think I got the location where should I change. Is that launchSettings.json file where I can configure my server application URL?. And as you said, It will pick up the connected Active directory from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164897/discussion-between-red-swan-and-camilo-terevinto).

Answer (score 1):

I am using Form Authentication for Domain users.

Middleware: CookieAuthentication

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "_system_authentication_cookie";                    
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;


                options.LoginPath = "/Login/Index/";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Login/Logout/";
                options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            });
```

LDAP authentication can be used

```
using Novell.Directory.Ldap;
public bool LoginLdap(string username, string password)
    {
        LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection();
        var loggedIn = false;
        try
        {
            connection.Connect(_config["Ldap:url"], LdapConnection.DEFAULT_PORT);
            connection.Bind(LdapConnection.Ldap_V3, _config["Ldap:domain"] + @"\" + username, password);
            loggedIn = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //throw new Exception("Login failed.");
            loggedIn = false;
        }

        connection.Disconnect();
        return loggedIn;


    }
```

Config.json

```
"Ldap": {
    "url": "ad.domain.net",
    "domain": "my-domain"
}
```